# JqGrid + Autocomplete

Tags: php, javascript, jqgrid

I'm having trouble implementing autocomplete in jqgrid. I've walked researching, alias until I based this question on a site that currently do not meet. The problem is this, I have to use the autocomplete several times throughout the application I'm developing. And now I have this function:

Javascript:

```
function autocomplete_element(value, options) {
    var $ac = $('<input type="text"/>');
    $ac.val(value);
    $ac.autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) 
    {        
        $.getJSON("autocomplete.php?id=estrategico",
            { q: request.term }, response);
    }
    });
    return $ac;
}
```

Jqgrid:

```
jQuery("#obj_oper_org").jqGrid({
    (...)
        {name:'COD_OBJ_EST',index:'COD_OBJ_EST', hidden: true, editable:true, editrules:{required:true, edithidden:true}, edittype : 'custom', editoptions : {'custom_element' : autocomplete_element}},
```

What was intended to pass a parameter to the javascript function more in order not to repeat forever the same function for each field because I need to be constantly changing url. Is it possible to make something of the genre? Sorry for the question but I do not have much experience in javascript, so I have some difficulties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you don't need to use `edittype : 'custom'` to be able to use jQuery UI Autocomplete. Instead of that you can use just `dataInit`.

You can define `myAutocomplete` function for example like

```
function myAutocomplete(elem, url) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(elem).autocomplete({
            source: url,
            minLength: 2,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $(elem).val(ui.item.value);
                $(elem).trigger('change');
            }
        });
    }, 50);
}
```

and then use

```
{ name:'COD_OBJ_EST', hidden: true, editable: true,
    editoptions: {
        dataInit: function (elem) {
            myAutocomplete(elem, "autocomplete.php?id=estrategico");
        }
    }}
```

Be careful that the name of parameter which will be send to the server is the standard name `term` instead of the name `q` which you currently use. I personally don't see any need to change the default name of the parameter.

Comment: Thank the genre was even something that was trying to implement the days.

Comment: Can you help me in a new doubts?

Comment: @UZUMAKI: What is the problem?

Comment: My autocomplete works as follows, shows the id and selecting this will be chosen. What is wanted to improve and show an acronym, acronym that load when you select the id. Do you understand what I want to do? How can I do this? eg: Autocomplete returns "Google, Microsoft, etc.", I choose google and would show me your id

Comment: @UZUMAKI: It seems be common question about usage of jQuery UI Autocomplete. Typical solution could be: you return from the server items with some properties like `value`, `desc` and so on. Additionally you overwrite `_renderItem` method of autocomplete of define child widget which base is jQuery UI Autocomplete. In the way you can display items of menu as combination of `value` and `desc`, but `value` will be used after the user make the choice.

Comment: hm ok ok. I'll try to do this if you need to go back to ask for help. Thank you once again

Comment: @UZUMAKI: If you will have implementation problems you should post new question where you detailed describe what you need to implement. Then you can post comment with the reference to new question.