# jqGrid autocomplete, select value and copy a value to another cell

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm working on a project with Visual Studio 2010 Asp.Net MVC4 and jqGrid.
when deploying the autocomplete and the user selects a value I need to copy a value to another cell as I can do to solve this problem? I attached a image and code.
[image]

this is my code, the autocomplete works, How I can copy a value to another cell from autocomplete?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var lastSelection;
    jQuery("#tbFacturaCompra").jqGrid({
        url: '@Url.Action("DatosFacturaCompra", "raFacturaCompra", new { area = "Operacion" })',
        editurl: '@Url.Action("DatosFacturaCompraABM", "raFacturaCompra", new { area = "Operacion" })',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'POST',
        postData: { IdOrden: IdOrden, ParTipoOrden: ParTipoOrden },
        colNames: ['Del', 'Nit', 'Factura', 'Autorizacion', '', 'Cod. Control', 'Fecha', 'Importe', 'Estado', '', ''],
        colModel:
        [
          { name: 'ac', width: 15, formatter: 'actions', formatoptions: { keys: true, editformbutton: false, delbutton: true, editbutton: false} },
          { name: 'ofc_nit', index: 'ofc_nit', align: 'right', width: '50', editable: true, edittype: 'text',
              editoptions: {
                  value : '',
                  dataInit: function (elem) {
                      value: ListarProveedores(elem);
                  }
              }
          },
          { name: 'ofc_nrofac', index: 'ofc_nrofac', align: 'right', width: '50', editable: true, edittype: 'text', editoptions: { style: "text-transform: uppercase"} },
          { name: 'ofc_autorizacion', index: 'ofc_autorizacion', align: 'right', width: '50', editable: true, edittype: 'text', editoptions: { style: "text-transform: uppercase"} },
          { name: 'ofc_alfanumerico', index: 'ofc_alfanumerico', editable: false, edittype: 'text', hidden: true },
          { name: 'ofc_codigocontrol', index: 'ofc_codigocontrol', align: 'right', width: '50', editable: true, edittype: 'text', editoptions: { style: "text-transform: uppercase"} },
          { name: 'ofc_fechafactura', index: 'ofc_fechafactura', align: 'center', width: '30', editable: true, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: "d-m-Y", newformat: "d/m/Y"} },
          { name: 'ofc_importe', index: 'ofc_importe', align: 'right', width: '25', editable: true, formatter: 'number', formatoptions: { decimalPlaces: 2} },
          { name: 'ofc_parestadofaccom', index: 'ofc_parestadofaccom', width: '20', editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: "V:V;F:F"} },
          { name: 'ofc_partipoorden', index: 'ofc_partipoorden', editable: true, edittype: 'text', hidden: true },
          { name: 'ofc_idordenpago', index: 'ofc_idordenpago', editable: true, edittype: 'text', hidden: true }
        ],
        pager: '#pg_tbFacturaCompra',
        rowNum: 15,
        rowList: [15, 30, 45],
        sortname: 'ofc_fechafactura',
        sortorder: 'desc',
        viewrecords: true,
        rownumbers: true,
        imgpath: '/content/themes/base/images',
        multiselect: false,
        height: 170,
        width: 700,
        footerrow: true,
        grid: true,
        toolbar: [true, "top"],
        loadComplete: function (data) {
            var id = $.jgrid.randId();
            var $grid = $('#tbFacturaCompra');
            var mydata = [{ ofc_nit: "", ofc_nrofac: "", ofc_autorizacion: "", ofc_alfanumerico: "-.-", ofc_codigocontrol: "", ofc_fechafactura: FechaServ, ofc_importe: "0.0", ofc_parestadofaccom: "V", ofc_partipoorden: ParTipoOrden, ofc_idordenpago: IdOrden}];
            $grid.jqGrid('addRowData', id, mydata[0], "first");
            $grid.jqGrid("editRow", id, true, '', '', '', '', reload);
        }});
});
```

**UPDATE**
Oleg this is code that contains Jquery UI Autocomplete:
In the return the value "Autorizacion" is **id: item.ofr_ultimaauto** in the autocomplete function "ListaProveedores" the value of "Autorizacion" item.id 
This form is for fast filling of bills (taxes)
The grid is not from the searching toolbar. When select value from autocomplete how I can copy id: item.ofr_ultimaauto to column "Autorizacion"?

> ```
> function getData(request, response) {
>     $.ajax({
>         url: '@Url.Action("BuscaRazonSocial", "raFacturaCompra", new { area = "Operacion" })',
>         type: 'GET',
>         dataType: 'json',
>         data: { term: request.term, maxResult: 20 },
>         success: function (data) {
>             response($.map(data, function (item) {
>                 return { label: item.ofr_nit, value: item.ofr_nit, id: item.ofr_ultimaauto, desc: item.ofr_razon };
>             }))
>         }
>     });
> }
> function ListarProveedores(elem) {
>     $(elem).autocomplete({ 
>         source: getData,
>         minLength: 5, 
>         autosearch: true,
>         select: function (event, ui) {
>          $(elem).val(ui.item.value);
>             $(elem).focus().trigger({ type: 'keypress', charCode: 13 });
>         }
>     }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
>         return $("<li>")
>         .append("<a class='ui-menu-item-titulo'><strong>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + " - </strong>" + item.id + "</a>")
>         .appendTo(ul);
>     };  
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code which you posted don't contains any call of jQuery UI Autocomplete. So I can't point you exact place of the code which you can extent. Nevertheless I try to explain what you can do. Typically one call `$(elem).autocomplete` inside of `dataInit`. jQuery UI Autocomplete supports `select` callback (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13932669/315935) an example) which you can use to set new value in `Autorizacion` column. You use `name: 'ofc_autorizacion'` for the column. So the `id` of the input field of the searching toolbar is `gs_ofc_autorizacion` and you can access it by `$("#gs_ofc_autorizacion").val("5031124051");`. It the data returned from the server for jQuery UI Autocomplete are in the format array of objects (for example array of objects with properties `value` and `autorizacion`) then you can find the same properties in `ui.item`. It can simplify your code. I hope you understand what I mean.

**UPDATED**: I see that the line above of the grid is not from the searching toolbar, but from inline editing. You use `var id = $.jgrid.randId();` as the id of the first row. So the id of the input field will be has `id + "_ofc_autorizacion"` instead of `"gs_ofc_autorizacion"`.

Comment: I already updated my question with the code autocomplete, I hope that you can help me?

Comment: @raranibar: Because `ofc_autorizacion` column has `editable: true` property the editable row should contains `<input name="ofc_autorizacion" id="123_ofc_autorizacion" type="text" .../>` (where 123 is rowid which you can find inside of `select` callback of Autocomplete as `$(elem).closest("tr").attr("id")`). So you can modify your `select` callback to about the following `select: function (event, ui) { $(elem).val(ui.item.value); $(elem).closest("tr").find("input[name=ofc_autorizacion]").val(ui.item.id); $(elem).focus().trigger({ type: "keypress", charCode: 13 }); }`