# Jqgrid Search with autocomplete, set value selected on field 'filters'

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, autocomplete

I work with JQgrid in the search dialog, one of the fields is autocomplete,
It works fine, but by the server side there is no value for the field.
you can see here :
request["filters"]= {"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"Name","op":"eq","data":""}]}

Here is my grid

```
  $("#myGrid").jqGrid({
    url: 'Handler.ashx',
    datatype: 'json',
    height: 250,
    direction: 'rtl',
    colNames: ['b', 'd', 'e', 'c', 'a'],
    colModel: [
                     { name: 'Semel', index: 'Semel', width: 80, sortable: true, formatter: semelFormatter },
                     { name: 'Name', width: 400, sortable: true ,searchoptions: {
               dataInit: function (elem) {
                     JqgridAuto(elem, "tyishuv", "yishuv", "shem", null);  }},
                     { name: 'Num', width: 50, sortable: true, align: "center" },
                     { name: 'date', width: 100, sortable: true },
                     { name: 'dateT', width: 100, sortable: true }

    ],
    rowNum: 200,
    postData: {       },
    rowList: [10, 20, 30, 200],
    pager: '#myGridPager',
    viewrecords: false,
    sortorder: 'asc'       
});
$("#myGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#myGridPager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false });
```

Here is the autocomplete function:

```
var JqgridAuto = function (elem, tableName, nameCodeFilde, dspl, code, localValue, fildeFilter) {
var funcName = "FetchList";
if (code == undefined)
    code = "Semel";
if (localValue == undefined)
    localValue = '';
if (fildeFilter == undefined)
    fildeFilter = '';

var autocompleteSource = function (request, response) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "AutoComplete.asmx/" + funcName,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        data: "{ 'Text':  '" + escape(request.term) + "','Code':'" + code + "','Dspl':'" + dspl + "','NumRecordes':'8','TableName':'" + tableName + "','fltr':'','Lfld':'" + localValue + "','Mfld':'" + fildeFilter + "','Desc':''}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
                if (!data.d.length) $(elem).val("");
            if (data.d.length == 1 && /^\d+$/.test(request.term)) {
                $(elem).val(data.d[0].Text);
                $("#" + nameCodeFilde).val(data.d[0].Semel);
                              }
            else {
                response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                    return {
                        value: item.Semel,
                        label: item.Shem
                    };
                }
                ));
            }//else
        },
        error: function (res, status) {
            alert(res.status + " : " + res.statusText + ". Status: " + status);
        }
    }); //END AJAX
};
$(elem).autocomplete({
    source: autocompleteSource,
    position: { collision: "flip" },
    minLength: 1,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $(elem).val(ui.item.label);
        $("#" + nameCodeFilde).val(ui.item.value);
    } 
}); //END AUOTOCOMPLETE
$('.ui-autocomplete').css('zIndex', 1000); // if autocomplete has misalignment so we are manually setting it 
if (elem.value != "0" && elem.value != '' && /^\d+$/.test(elem.value))
    $(elem).autocomplete('search', elem.value);
```

};

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that your main problem can be solved by triggering `"change"` event on the `elem` directly after autocomplete set the value returned from the server. So you should add the line

```js
$(elem).trigger("change");
```

inside of `select` callback. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13932669/315935) for the code example.

Additionally I should mention that the code, which you use for Autocomplete, seems me too complex and not full correct. For example the line

```js
data: "{ 'Text':  '" + escape(request.term) + "','Code':'" + code + "','Dspl':'" +
    dspl + "','NumRecordes':'8','TableName':'" + tableName + "','fltr':'','Lfld':'" +
    localValue + "','Mfld':'" + fildeFilter + "','Desc':''}"
```

contains **manual** conversion of object to JSON string. Moreover you use `'` instead of `"` for strings. It's wrong. Only the old Microsoft implementation of ASMX web serveries tolerate this. I recommend you to use object as `data` instead and call `JSON.stringify`:

```js
data: JSON.stringify({
    Text: request.term,
    Code: code,
    Dspl: dspl,
    NumRecordes: "8",
    TableName: tableName,
    fltr: "",
    Lfld: localValue,
    Mfld: fildeFilter,
    Desc: ""
})
```

Additionally you should add call of `response` callback inside of `error` callback too. See the following

> It's important when providing a custom source callback to handle
>   errors during the request. You must always call the response callback
>   even if you encounter an error.

in [the documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) of jQuery UI Autocomplete.