# can make celledit to dropdown and multiselect with jqgrid?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jqgrid

```
$.(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'xx_op.php',
        ...success: function(result) {
            result = JSON.parse(result);
            var colNames = result.columnNames;
            var colModel = result.colModel;
            $.("list").jqGrid({
                colNames: colNames,
                colModel: colModel,
                cellEdit: true,
                cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
                afterSaveCell: function(rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
                    var y = $("group_list").getChangedCells('dirty');
                    var t = JSON.stringify(y);
                    $.ajax({
                        ....
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

can you understand my meanings?
I want to set celledit to dropdown and multiselect,so how can i write code? 
This is renderings that I want to achieve finally .  And each colnames are like picture and values are different from colnames to other colnames

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nslkO.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the edittype and editoptions for your column which you want to be multi select options.

[Here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3Aoptions)  is also helpful link on multiselects

Here is a soltion I created for you in  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/helengeb/nk9zLLn2/4/)

```
 var mydata = [
                    {id: "10", Name: "dog",     Singleselect: "1", Multiselect: [1]},
                    {id: "20", Name: "cat", Singleselect: "1", Multiselect: [2]},
                    {id: "30", Name: "fish",    Singleselect: "2", Multiselect: [3, 4]},
                    {id: "40", Name: "elephant",      Singleselect: "2", Multiselect: [4]}
                ],
                lastSel;
            $("#list").jqGrid({
                data: mydata,
                cellEdit:true,
                datatype: "local",
                cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
                colModel: [
                    { name: "Name", width: 130 },
                    { name: "Singleselect", width: 100, formatter: "select", edittype: "select",
                        editoptions: {
                            value: {"1": "sport", "2": "science"},
                            size: 2
                        }
                    },
                    { name: "Multiselect", width: 250,
                        formatter: "select",
                        edittype: "custom",
                        editoptions: {
                            value: {"1": "Swim", "2": "Eat 1", "3": "drink", "4": "bark"},
                            custom_element: function (value, options) {
                                return $.jgrid.createEl.call(this, "select",
                                    $.extend(true, {}, options, {custom_element: null, custom_value: null}),
                                    value);
                            },
                            custom_value: function ($elem, operation, value) {
                                if (operation === "get") {
                                    return $elem.val();
                                }
                            },
                            multiple: true
                        }
                    }
                ],
                cmTemplate: { editable: true },
                gridview: true,
                sortname: "Name",
                sortorder: "desc",
                viewrecords: true,
                rownumbers: true,
                pager: "#pager",
                height: "100%",
                editurl: "clientArray",

                caption: "Multi select options"
            });
```

Comment: your example is working ,but it's not mine.Mine colmodel ande colname are from getdata_op.php,so i have to set them in php file,select options is database,it's also can say every datas being get in database.And I don't know if you can understand my thought.In a word ,thanks

Comment: I have upload my renderings,and hope you help me

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP add this in where ever you are creatign the column model
SEe also the solution in 
[Here that Oleg created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932264/jqgrid-autocomplete) which is a similar with yours

```
  editoptions: 
   {
      'custom_element': multiselectcallback,
      'custom_value': multiselectvalue,
       multiple: true
   }
```

Then put those to javascript

```
function multiselectcallback(value, options) {
   //get dropdown values using ajax and load them on success 
   $.get( "xx_op.php/getdropdownlistdata", function(result) {
    return $.jgrid.createEl.call(this, "select", $.extend(true, {}, options, {custom_element: null, custom_value: null}), result);                                   
 }
```

function multiselectvalue(elem, op, v) {

```
if (operation === "get") 
 {
  return $elem.val();
}
```

Comment: I 'm trying your example,but result is dynamic ,it's choosen by colnames, how i should to design the getdropdownlistdata function?

Comment: What do you mean by that please clarify it?

Comment: getdropdownlistdata  is your server side method and design it such a way that it reurns the dropdown list key:value pairs.

Comment: if i can add function->onCellSelect:function(rowid,iCol,cellcontent){  display a dialog which can use dropdown and multiple using your answer ways  }

Comment: I do that for your addvice,but have wrong,diaplay:function "custom_element" return value is required!.   my php code :echo json_encode($value,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);style:{"0“:"c","1":"java","2":"js"},  what should i do